# Why run_in_executor placed in BaseEventLoop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

For example, `asyncio.gather` has signature `asyncio.gather(*coros_or_futures, loop=None, return_exceptions=False)`.

I can pass specific loop or leave `None` (and default event loop will be used).

Why doesn't `BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor` defined same way, like: `asyncio.run_in_executor(executor, callback, *args, loop=None)`?

If there was some important reason to place it into `BaseEventLoop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically `run_in_executor` appeared very early and it was an event loop's method. It's modeled after twisted's methods for running code in thread pool. After appearing the `run_in_executor` has never changed.
It's low-level function, that accepts callback and sits pretty close to other functions which accepts callback, not couroutine: `call_soon()`, `call_later()`, `add_reader()` etc. All those are methods of event loop.

`asyncio.gather` was invited much later, after about a year of the library development. It is placed on higher abstraction level, works with coroutines and pushed along with other coroutine-related functions like `wait()` or `sleep()`.